# Definition of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

Question: Prove or disprove the following: Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open $U \supset E$ such that the outer measure of $E, |E|_e > |U| - \epsilon$ then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I believe this statement is false since the definition of Lebesgue measurable set is slightly different. That is given any $\epsilon >0$ there exists open $U \supset E$ such that $$|U- E|_e < \epsilon.$$

However, I can't seem to find any non-measurable sets that satisfy the following hypothesis to show a counterexample. Any hints/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be interested in the case $E \subset \mathbb{ R }^1$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Marlene  yeah sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

( notation: Lebesgue outer measure $m^*( E )$ )

Let $E \subset \mathbb{ R }^1$ ( Lebesgue measurable or not Lebesgue measurable).
Suppose $m^*( E )$ is finite.

We will show for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an open set $U \supset E$ such that $m^*( E ) > m^*( U ) - \epsilon$.

By definition, $m^*( E ) = \inf \{ \sum_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } L( J_n ) : E \subset \cup_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } J_n \}$,
where $J_n$ is a bounded open interval and $L$ is the length of the interval.

Let $\epsilon > 0$.
Since $m^*( E )$ is finite, there is a sequence of open intervals $( J_n )$ such that $E \subset \cup_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } J_n$ and
$\sum_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } L( J_n ) < m^*( E ) + \epsilon$. $\:$
$\cup_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } J_n$ is an open set. $\:$
Let $U = \cup_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } J_n$. $\:$
$E \subset U$.

$$m^*( U ) = m^*( \cup_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } J_n ) \le \sum_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } m^*( J_n ) =
\sum_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } L( J_n )$$

$$m^*( U ) \le \sum_{ n = 1 }^{ \infty } L( J_n ) < m^*( E ) + \epsilon$$

$$m^*( U ) - \epsilon < m^*( E )$$